# ConoHa VPS APPサーバーからDBサーバーに接続

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, conoha

VPS APPサーバーを作成し(CentOS 7.2)し、 ConoHaのアプリケーションサーバー項目からDBサーバーを追加しました。
一通り設定を済ませて

```
ping -c 3 private.****.****.database-hosting.conoha.io
```

とすると

```
 PING private.unit01.database-hosting.tyo1.conoha.io (172.21.74.19) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 172.21.74.19: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.455 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.74.19: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.372 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.74.19: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.408 ms

--- private.unit01.database-hosting.tyo1.conoha.io ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.372/0.411/0.455/0.041 ms
```

と返ったので、続いてmysql接続をしようと

```
mysql -u **** -h private.***.***.database-hosting.conoha.io -p *****
```

と打ったら

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

と返ってきました。

いろいろ調べてみましたら、原因はパスが通ってないなど出てきたのですが、そもそもAPPサーバーの方にもデータベースをインストールしなくてはいけないのでしょうか？
APPサーバーからデータベースがインストールされているDBサーバーにアクセスするというイメージだったのですが、根本的になにか間違っていますでしょうか？

ConoHa側の設定では主に下記のチュートリアルを見て行い
[DBサーバー接続用ネットワークを使う](https://www.conoha.jp/conoben/archives/9103)

ターミナル側では下記の設定にしました。
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=172.21.***.**
NETMASK=255.255.254.0
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1

```
[東京リージョンのIPアドレス] via eth1のゲートウェイのIPアドレス
[東京リージョンのIPアドレス] dev eth1
```

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。MariaDBのクライアントをインストールすることにより無事に動作いたしました。
ただ、そのあとのログインがうまくいかなかったので、もう少し調べてみようと思います。
またこちらで質問するかもしれませんが、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: おめでとうございます。問題が解決したのであれば回答を承認するようにしてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App サーバーから DB サーバーへアクセスするという認識は間違っていません。
症状を見る限り、単に App サーバー側に mysql クライアントがインストールされていないだけではないかと思われます。
mysql サーバーと mysql クライアントはパッケージが分かれています。DB サーバーへアクセスするだけならクライアントパッケージさえあれば OK です。

なお CentOS は、7からはデータベースの標準に MySQL ではなく [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/ja/) が採用されました。（[CentOS Product Specifications](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product)）

ConoHa のデータベースサーバーが MySQL なのか MariaDB なのかは把握していませんが、[アプリケーションサーバーを追加する - ConoHa](https://www.conoha.jp/guide/appserver.php) の記述を見る限り

> 「アプリケーションサーバー」は、手軽に使えるメールサーバーやDBサーバー(MySQL互換)を作成します。

とあるので MariaDB が導入されているものと推測します。

したがって App サーバー側では MariaDB のクライアントをインストールすれば良いものと思われます。

---

結論としては、App サーバー側で

```
$ yum install MariaDB-client
```

とすることで MariaDB のクライアントがインストールされます。これで mysql コマンドが使用できるはずです。